# Determine the probability using other given statements

Tags: probability

So I have the given probabilities:

$\mathbb{P}(M\cap A\cap B)=0.064$, $\mathbb{P}(M \cap A\cap B^c)=0.192$ and $\mathbb{P}(M \cap A^c \cap B)=0.084$

Is there any way to determine $\mathbb{P}(M^c\cap A^c \cap B^c)$ using the following statements and that I have $\mathbb{P}(A)=0.4$, $\mathbb{P}(B)=0.8$ and $\mathbb{P}(M)=0.36$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, something's wrong with these numbers:

Since $P(M\cap A\cap B)=0.064$, and $P(M\cap A^C \cap B)=0.084$, we have $P(M\cap B)=0.148$, and hence $P(M\cap B^C)=0.212$, meaning $P(B^C) \ge 0.212$, and $P(B) \le 0.788$, which contradicts $P(B)=0.8$

Anyway, even if you had numbers that do make sense, this is not possible ... you can figure out the difference between $P(M^C\cap A^C \cap B)$ and $P(M^C\cap A \cap B^C)$, but you cannot figure out their value by themselves ... *Unless* a bunch of them are forced to take on the minimum of $0$ ... I wonder if that was what the problem was meant to be... can you check the numbers?